# Using a counterexample to prove the converse is not true in a proof on converging in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

It is known that if the expectation of $|A_{n} - A|$ tends to zero, then $A_{n} \xrightarrow{p} A$ where $p$ in this case means it is converging in probability. We can prove this using Markov's inequality. However, the converse is not true. $A_{n} \xrightarrow{p} A$ does not imply the expectation of $|A_{n} - A|$ tends to zero. I have been trying to obtain a simple counterexample.

One idea I tried was defining $A_{n}$ as a piece wise defined function where its equal to $x^3$ with probability $\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^2}$ or its equal to $0$ with probability $1 - \displaystyle\frac{1}{x^2}$. The problem with this is that I don't think the way I defined it depends on $n$.

I would be very appreciative if someone could help me obtain a counterexample to the converse. Or maybe change mine around a little if its just missing a couple of details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of $([0,1],\mathscr B, P)$ and imagine a sequence of random variables $\{A_n\}$, that is a sequence of measurable functions defined on $[0,1]$. Let $A=0$ and $A_n=n^2$ over an interval whose width is $\frac{1}{n}$ and zero otherwise. $E[A_n]=n$ then. Since the interval is shrinking whit $n$, we can say that our sequence converges in probability to $A=0$. But as we saw the expectation is yet increasing.

**Told in a simpler language**

$A_n$ is a random variable taking the value $n^2$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ and $0$ with probability $1-\frac{1}{n}$. Now $E[A_n]\rightarrow\infty$ and $P(A_n>0)\rightarrow0.$

Comment: Will this work for any scaling of $n$? For example Could I let it take on the value of $n^5$ with probability $\frac{1}{n^4}$? Also when we say that it takes the value of $n^2$, what does that actually mean. Is $n \in [0,1]$?

Comment: Did you read the "simpler languge" version? There I wrote down without any fancy meaasure theory that $A_n$'s were random variables. $n=1,2,...$ were the indices. That is $n$ cannot be in [0,1]. However $A_n$ can be even $n^{110}$ with pr $1/n$ or $1/n^{212}$. In the latter case we do not have a counterexample, though.